# how to add a UIView file on a MainView as a subview

Tags: xcode, ipad, uiview

If I already have a UIViewController(no nib) on iphone,and I wanna use it on ipad.
I use a IBOutlet(UIView)on ipad to show this view.

I try to set in viewDidLoad :

MacroMainView *marcoview =[[MacroMainView alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

marcoView =[marcoview view];

[[self view]addSubview:marcoView];

but still no work..
What should I do??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use loadView method for a UIViewController without a nib. [UIViewController Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> If you create your views manually, you must override this method and use it to create your views

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding you correctly. Is MacroMainView a subclass of UIViewController or UIView? What do you mean with your statement: I use a IBOutlet(UIView)on ipad to show this view. Maybe you should restate your problem?